# jQuery find() function doens't find a element

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have two questions.

QUESTION 1) 
I'm trying to get a text of table, first tr, first td. 
I think it is same first line code and second line code, 
but second line doesn't get a text.

Who's know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="ko">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // first line
            var test = $(document).find('table:eq(0)').find('tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();

            // second line
            var test2 = $(document).find('table:eq(0) > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text(); <== doesn't work
            alert(test);
            alert(test2);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="head">
            <td>num</td>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>author</td>
            <td>ip_address</td>
            <td>post_time</td>
            <td>count_review</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

QUESTION 2) 
I have tested a following code by using ajax. 
Also following code displayes a white space. 
I have tried a number of differnce code, I can't know cause of showing a whie space.. 
How to get a text of td tag in this code..

html body code is same with abobe.

```
<script>
    function readMsgByAjax() {
        var send_data = "num=" + 1;

        $.post(
                "PHP_readReply_sql.php",
                send_data,
                function (data) {
                    var test = $(data).find('table:eq(0)').find('tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
                    alert("data : " + test); // <= this displays a white space.
               )
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Modern browsers wraps tr's in `<tbody>` just see the generated HTML. Any you are looking for immediate child using `>` so it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `tr` wont be a child of `table`, there will be `tbody` in between them when it is rendered.. so your child selector won't work

try

```
var test2 = $('table:eq(0) > tbody > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
```

another solution is to use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)

```
var test2 = $('table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
```

So in your first code you are using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which work like a descendant selector that is why it is working

To match your second version, the first version could be

```
var test = $(document).children('table:eq(0)').find('tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
```

Comment: I am surprised that *you* left the redundant $(document) on the finds :) `var test2 = $('table:eq(0) > tbody > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();`

Comment: Also the second version will match nested tables, so advise use with caution.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I think since OP said the first version is working fine... what OP is looking for is a combined selector instead of using .find()... then OP used a child selector instead of descendant when he combined them

Comment: Thanks Arun and everyone and I have been knew about tbody.

Comment: In QUESTION2, I tried a code like this => var test = $(data).find('table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text();  This code may has a any fault?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var test2 = $(document).find('table:eq(0) > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
```

It will work

```
var test2 = $(document).find('table:eq(0) tbody tr:eq(0)  td:eq(0)').text();
```

The Problem in your case is that in modern browsers `tr's` gets wrapped with `tbody` so `tr` is not a child of `table`.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/acq2zow3/1/)

Comment: Be aware that this will also match nested tables, better to add tbody.

Answer (score 1):

As other mention browsers add a `TBODY` element automatically above the `TR`s if it is missing in the HTML.

Use:

```
var test2 = $('table:eq(0) > tbody > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();
```

Note: you have redundant `$(document)` on your searches too (removed here).

If you use a descendant selector as other suggest, please be advised it will also match nested tables within your table:

```
 var test2 = $('table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)').text();   // BEWARE this Will match nested tables :)
```